# repeating timer functionality and logic

Tags: javascript, timer, repeat

I'm creating pomodoro timer- interval should repeat with different duration after first one completes. simplified non working exampe:

```
var firstDuration=5;
var secondDuration=10;

var timer=setInterval(()=>{
firstDuration--
if (firstDuration<0){
clearInterval(timer) .. 
//secondDuration-- dont know how to continue..
```

What is the best way to implement such functionality? Also i plan to use Date.now() rather than -- .

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: @NicholasTower I'm creating pomodoro timer- interval should repeat with different duration after first one completes. Thanks.

Comment: So, you want a timer to go off after 5 seconds, and then one to go off 10 seconds after that (for a total of 15 seconds)? And after those 15 seconds are we done, or do we start over with another 5 second timeout?

Comment: @NicholasTower Pomodoro timers have "work" session and "break" session. Lets say 20 mins and 5 mins. Work session starts the countdown, and when it finishes it clears the timer and break session starts a countdown. Thus looping one after another. No total sum needed. Countdowns are displayed on the screen. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @NicholasTower timers start emediately, for example when user pushes "start" .  Let's say it countdowns from 10 to zero every second,  resets,  then countdowns from 5 to zero everysecond. Then first one starts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i've understood the requirements correctly, this will do what you want. It will have a timer go off every second until 20 minutes have elapsed, then every second until 5 minutes have elapsed. At that point it starts over with the 20 minute countdown.

```
const workDurationSeconds = 20 * 60;
const breakDurationSeconds = 5 * 60;

function startCountdown(session) {
    let duration;
    if (session === 'work') {
      duration = workDurationSeconds;
    } else {
      duration = breakDurationSeconds;
    }

    let id = setInterval(() => {
      duration--;
      if (duration <= 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
        startCountdown(session === 'work' ? 'break' : 'work');
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! I just added default parameter as 'work' because it started the countdown from breakDuration.    'function startCountdown(session='work') {'